# R - unpivot & substring

Tags: r

I'm looking for a base r solution for to unpivot and substring my original data set. example below;

```
ID  L1  L2  L3
1   AABBCC  BACA    
2   AAAAAA  BACBA   CACCC
3   BBACB   BACA    CABAC
4           
5   BCBDAB  ACAA    CBABA

dput(original_data):
structure(list(ID = 1:5, L1 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("","AAAAAA", "AABBCC", "BBACB", "BCBDAB"), class = "factor"), L2 = structure(c(3L,4L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "ACAA", "BACA", "BACBA"), class = "factor"),L3 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("", "CABAC","CACCC","CBABA"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "L1","L2", "L3"),class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

to a longer table whilst taking a substring of 3 overlapping consecutive characters, example below;

```
ID  Column  Position    Substring
1   L1  1   AAB
1   L1  2   ABB
1   L1  3   BBC
1   L1  4   BCC
1   L1  5   CC
1   L1  6   C
1   L2  1   BAC
1   L2  2   ACA
1   L2  3   AC
1   L2  4   A
2   L1  1   AAA
2   L1  2   AAA
2   L1  3   AAA
2   L1  4   AAA
2   L1  5   AA
2   L1  6   A
2   L2  1   BAC
2   L2  2   ACB
2   L2  3   CBA
2   L2  4   BA
2   L2  5   A
2   L3  1   CAC
2   L3  2   ACC
2   L3  3   CCC
2   L3  4   CC
2   L3  5   C
```

does anybody have any ideas how to do this? my problem is that I cannot use external libraries such as reshap2. I need to do this in base r.

Comment: Your "structure" for your sample data is broken, it doesn't paste into R correctly. Can you please try again?

Comment: thanks, I think I've corrected this. how about now?

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that computes the substrings of a string. Test:

```
bits = function(s){
    s=as.character(s)
    substring(s,1:nchar(s),2+(1:nchar(s)))
}

> bits("ABCDEF")
[1] "ABC" "BCD" "CDE" "DEF" "EF"  "F"
```

Now write a function to do a single row, which uses `lapply` over the three L variables and combines the results:

```
dorow = function(rr){
    do.call(
        rbind,
        lapply(1:3,
               function(L){
                   s=rr[[paste0("L",L)]]
                   ts = bits(s)
                   data.frame(
                       ID=rr[["ID"]],
                       Column=paste0("L",L),
                       Position=1:length(ts),
                       Substring=ts)
               }
               )
    )
}
```

Test this:

```
> dorow(d[1,])
   ID Column Position Substring
1   1     L1        1       AAB
2   1     L1        2       ABB
3   1     L1        3       BBC
4   1     L1        4       BCC
5   1     L1        5        CC
6   1     L1        6         C
7   1     L2        1       BAC
8   1     L2        2       ACA
9   1     L2        3        CA
10  1     L2        4         A
11  1     L3        1          
12  1     L3        2
```

Returns some blanks but we'll fix that later.

Write a function to loop over rows, call `dorow`, and combine. Filter out the empty strings here:

```
dodata = function(d){
    dd = do.call(
        rbind,
        lapply(1:nrow(d),
               function(r){dorow(d[r,])})
    )
    dd[dd$Substring!="",]
}
```

And test...

```
> d
  ID     L1    L2    L3
1  1 AABBCC  BACA      
2  2 AAAAAA BACBA CACCC
3  3  BBACB  BACA CABAC
> head(dodata(d),16)
   ID Column Position Substring
1   1     L1        1       AAB
2   1     L1        2       ABB
3   1     L1        3       BBC
4   1     L1        4       BCC
5   1     L1        5        CC
6   1     L1        6         C
7   1     L2        1       BAC
8   1     L2        2       ACA
9   1     L2        3        CA
10  1     L2        4         A
13  2     L1        1       AAA
14  2     L1        2       AAA
15  2     L1        3       AAA
16  2     L1        4       AAA
17  2     L1        5        AA
18  2     L1        6         A
>
```

Look right?

Comment: thanks so much, this works so well! just two things; 1) I'm getting some empty rows still, 2) at the moment, the code works for columns "L1,L2,L3" as provided in my example. how can I extend it to work for columns  "C1,C2,C3,L1,L2,L3" ? thanks again

Comment: I dont get any empty rows from your test data so you must be running it on something that isn't quite like your test data. Maybe there's space characters in the blanks rather than empty strings of zero length? Adjust the test in the end of `dodata` to fix.

Comment: To work over a set of named columns, edit `dorow` to loop over the names of the columns (`lapply(column_names,function(col){...})`) and extract the data from `rr` by name (`s=rr[[col]]`) and make sure you put `Column=col` when constructing the row.